# Get model from a cuid in Redux Actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've go a Redux Actions file : contributionActions

My function is :

```
  export function acceptContribution(contributionCuid) {
  return dispatch => {
    const {
      //How can I construct contribution from  contributionCuid
      contriution: { activity } } = contributionCuid;
    dispatch(actionStart(CONTRIBUTIONS_TO_VALIDATE_REMOVE));
    Mixpanel.track('acceptContribution2', {
      'Mission': contribution.activity.name,
      'Charity': contribution.activity.charity.name,
    });
    return callApi(`contributions/${contributionCuid}/accept`, 'post')
      .then(() => dispatch(removeContributionToValidateAction(contributionCuid)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(actionError(CONTRIBUTIONS_TO_VALIDATE_REMOVE, err)));
  };
}
```

Now I want to send information about this contribution to Mixpanel. So I need to reconstruct contribution so I can get all the value I need.
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't deconstruct the contribution you're getting from the parameter.

I've modified your code:

```
export function acceptContribution(contributionCuid) {
  return dispatch => {
    // do not deconstruct the contribution object, so we keep a reference to it -- is it really needed?
    const { contribution } = contributionCuid;
    // you get the activity here
    const { activity } = contribution;

    dispatch(actionStart(CONTRIBUTIONS_TO_VALIDATE_REMOVE));
    Mixpanel.track('acceptContribution2', {
      'Mission': activity.name,
      'Charity': activity.charity.name,
    });
    return callApi(`contributions/${contributionCuid}/accept`, 'post')
      .then(() => dispatch(removeContributionToValidateAction(contributionCuid)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(actionError(CONTRIBUTIONS_TO_VALIDATE_REMOVE, err)));
  };
}
```

Do you really want to call that `Mixpanel` function from inside your reducer actions? I like to keep my reducers dealing with exclusively that.

Comment: Yes thanks. But lik this contribution is still undefined.